# JMETER : Random time stamps replacement in HTTP requests as string (Parameterization of time stamp)

Tags: jmeter, date-format

I would like to submit one json payload for 1000 times using Jmemter. 
auth *time stamp suppose to be unique in each request*.

To make it unique written script in Beanshell Preprocessor. 
Beanshell Preprocessor returning date in required format.

But variable was replaced as integer but I want it in String with quotes.

Coming as :  "last_auth_timestamp": 2019-07-21T12:35:59.201+0000,
Expecting  : "last_auth_timestamp": "2019-07-21T12:35:59.201+0000",

Comment: BTW your expected and actual results in question are the same

Answer (score 1):

Use [__time](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) function with [date format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
 "${__time(yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssSSSXX)}"
```

Comment: I did that ..but it is returning  time stamp without quotes.Coming as : "last_auth_timestamp": 2019-07-21T12:35:59.201+0000,
Expecting : "last_auth_timestamp": "2019-07-21T12:35:59.201+0000",

Comment: @naga add quotes before and after

Comment: import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

Date date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate()+5);
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'+'SSSS");
String formattedDate = df.format(date);
vars.put("date",formattedDate);

Comment: {
    "name" : "asdfsadfsad",
    "last_auth_timestamp": ${date}
    
}

Comment: date is getting replaced without quotes

Comment: @naga `last_auth_timestamp": "${date}"`